# NSComboBox: How to tell user has typed in information that is not in the pop up list and read it

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-bindings

I have an NSComboBox with a seperate class that conforms to NSComboBox dataSource and delegate.

If the user types text into the combo box that that does not match one of the items in the pop up list, how do I receieve a notification that the user has typed something in and also read the value that the user has typed?

At the moment I'm implimenting the delegate methods:-

```
-(void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification 
-(void)comboBoxWillDismiss:(NSNotification *)notification
```

However these appear only to be notified when the user has selected an item from the popup, not when the user types something else in stops editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `NSComboBox` is a subclass of `NSTextField`, and thus `NSControl`, you can also use the [`NSControlTextEditingDelegate` methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSControlTextEditingDelegate) such as [`control:textShouldEndEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate/control:textShouldBeginEditing:) to affect the behavior of your combo box.

Comment: Thanks Josh, exactly what I was looking for. I had thought about NSTextFieldDelegate but didn't think to look further back.